# Symfony, Class not found if i don't build_bootstrap whenever

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, browser-cache

I had problem with new classes in my project. I created two classes but when I load Controller from browser the browser answer me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '......\CompanyTotals\CompanyTotals' not found in /var/www/html/...../Wallet/WalletFactory.php on line 206
```

If i launch in project folder the command:

```
composer install
```

or

```
sudo php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

When i launch the app from browser it works well only for first load of the page, than the second time gives me the error back.

Can someone helm me to solve this strange problem?

The permission on project is for the major of the file root root, in the app folder, the file bootstrap.php.cache can be created as root root if i use sudo on composer install or mario mario, if i use command without sudo.

The results is the same.

Comment: Please share more details. Where is that class located?

Comment: The  class is located in src/mioprogetto/Bundle/AppBundle/Fiscal/CompanyTotals

Comment: That does not look good: how did you configure the autoloader to find that class?

Comment: Show your(s) controller(s), the routes and how you call your class.
Is your class declare as service ? Have you set to true autowiring ?

Comment: Whats the output when you run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: My class is declared like service in services.yml of Bundle/resource/config/ like all other classes of project:
    mioprogetto\Bundle\AppBundle\ ... \CompanyTotals\CompanyTotalsClass:
        class: Miobenefit\Bundle\AppBundle\ ... \CompanyTotals\CompanyTotalsClass
        autowire: true
But I think that declaration it's ok, because after 
composer install 
the web page works well and load classes properties and show them on page.
The problems comes the second time that I load the page.

Comment: After composer autoload the response is:
Generating autoload files
> ComponentInstaller\Installer::postAutoloadDump
Compiling component files
Generated autoload files